# React Spreadsheet Viewer App Edit Rendering - Large Data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, optimization, next.js

I'm building a Chrome extension for work. I'm limited in permissions, so setting up a server wasn't an option. We use a ton of CSV data, and using google sheets with their timeout limit just wasn't working for us. I decided to build a "csv merger" app that allowed us to easily extract data from multiple and combined it or create rules to transform data. With that, and a customizable web crawler app, I needed something visual for the employees as they have a hard time understanding what's happening under the hood. I decided to build a fairly simple csv viewer mostly for reference so they could visually see the data transforming and more easily write rules for it. So far I'm having two issues.

The first issue was with rendering the large csv files to the screen on upload. I basically solved that issue with a somewhat messy use of the intersection observer, breaking it into loadable chunks. The problem there was that with the intersection observer, apparently, the data gets rendered out after you scroll far enough away(?). I kind of fixed it by adding "perspective=1px" which definitely made it better, but also causes the intersection observer to not respect the rootMargin I set...Still working that out too.

useObserver.tsx

```js
'use client'

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

type Options = {
    root?: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement> | HTMLElement | null,
    rootMargin?: string,
    threshold?: number
}
type Action = ((entries: any[])=>void);
const isEl = (root: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement> | HTMLElement | null | undefined): root is HTMLElement => {
    return true;
}

export default function useObserver(action: Action, options: Options) {
    const {rootMargin, threshold} = options;
    const root = options.root==null?null:isEl(options.root)?options.root:options.root.current!;
    const obs = useRef<IntersectionObserver|null>(null)
    const exists = useRef<string[]|null>(null)
    const [added, setAdded] = useState<[number, number]>([0,0])
    const ref = useRef<HTMLElement[]|null>(null)
    const stopObserve = useRef<(()=>void)|null>(null)

    const setRef = (newRef: HTMLElement | null)=>{
        if(newRef==null||!newRef.id){
            return
        }
        if(ref.current){
            const refExists = ref.current.findIndex(rc=>{
                return newRef.id===rc.id
            })
            if(refExists>-1){
                // console.log(ref.current)
                return;
            }
        }
        
        ref.current = !ref.current?[newRef]:[...ref.current, newRef] ;
       
        return
    }


    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries: any[])=>action(entries), 
            {
                root, 
                rootMargin,
                threshold,
            }
        )
        obs.current = observer;
        const loader = async()=>setTimeout(()=>{
            if(ref.current&&ref.current.length<=added[1]) return;
            setAdded([added[0]+1, !ref.current?0:ref.current.length])
            stopObserve.current = ()=>obs.current!.disconnect()
            loader()
        }, 3000)
        loader()
    }, [root, rootMargin, threshold, action, added])


    useEffect(()=>{
        if(ref.current == null){
            console.log('no refs');
            return
        }
        if(!obs || obs.current == null){
            console.log('no refs');
            return
        }
        const setR = ref.current!;
        for(let o = 0; o<setR.length; o++){
            if(exists.current &&exists.current.includes(setR[o].id))return;
            obs.current.observe(setR[o])
            exists.current = !exists.current?[setR[o].id]:[...exists.current, setR[o].id]
        }
        return () => {
            for(let o = 0; o<setR.length; o++){
                const obsr = setR[o];
                obs.current!.unobserve(obsr)
            }
        }
    },[obs, added])

    return {setRef, stopObserve: stopObserve.current};
}
```

Observer Setup >>>>> in CsvView.tsx

```js
    const options = {
        root: null, 
        rootMargin: `2500px`, 
        threshold: 0, 
    }

    const {setRef, stopObserve} = useObserver(action, options)

    function action(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]){
        entries.forEach(entry=>{
            if(!segments.current){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    action(entries)
                }, 2000)
            }
            else if(segments.current&&entry.isIntersecting){
                if([...segments.current.entries()].length>chunk.current.load){
                    console.log(chunk.current.load)
                    const setSeg = segments.current[chunk.current.load]
                    pageSegments.current = !pageSegments.current?[setSeg]:[...pageSegments.current, setSeg]
                    chunk.current = {amountPerView: chunk.current.amountPerView, load: chunk.current.load+1}
                    setPageSet(prev=>prev+1)
                }

            }
        })
    }
```

The bigger issue I'm now facing is editing the Cells. I added a double click to edit feature, and it does start to edit it, but when I make a change the app pretty much freezes up for almost a minute and my assumption is that is because everything is rerendering. Is there any way to avoid this?

I'm honestly hoping there is a way I can make a visual change to the screen without rerendering the entire list. I don't really need the on-screen 'csv data' as it's just visual. I want to create a context that saves the changes by row and cell id, and then updates the csvMapped data to make changes that will be used later. For example, when comparing two csvs, they wouldn't reference the value on the page, but the mapped data in memory, but a function would be called before a download action for example, that would take the saved changes and then apply them. I haven't created the functions for that yet, but I was hoping that would allow me to avoid the bigger renders. Is it possible to use contentEditable attribute to by-pass the react rendering and pass the changes for the update function later?

CsvView.tsx

```js
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import useObserver from '../hooks/useObserver';
import CsvContainer from "./CsvContainer";


type Props = {
    csv: Map<string, Map<string, string>>
}

export default function CsvView(props: Props) {
    const {csv} = props;

    const spreadsheetRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null) as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    const chunk = useRef<{load: number, amountPerView: number}>({load: 0, amountPerView: 20})

    const [csvMap, setCsvMap] = useState<Map<string, Map<string, string>>| null>(null)
    const segments = useRef<Map<string, string>[][]|null>(null)
    const rowHeight = useRef<number>(25)
    const rootElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
    const pageSegments = useRef<Map<string, string>[][]|null>(null)
    const [pagesSet, setPageSet] = useState<number>(0)

    useEffect(()=>{
        setCsvMap(csv)
    }, [csv])

    const initCsv = useCallback(async () => {
        const ssCurr = spreadsheetRef.current
        if(ssCurr == null||csvMap==null){
            console.log('not ready')
            return;
        }
        const csvLength = [...csvMap.values()].length
        const containerHeight = spreadsheetRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        const amountPerView = Math.floor((containerHeight+3000)/rowHeight.current)+5;
        const numberOfLoads = Math.floor(csvLength/amountPerView);
        const csvValues = [...csvMap!.values()];
        chunk.current ={...chunk, load: 0, amountPerView}
        for(let load = 0; load<=numberOfLoads; load++){
            if(!segments.current&&load<=numberOfLoads){
                segments.current = [csvValues.splice(0, amountPerView)]
            }
            else if(!segments.current&&load>numberOfLoads){
                segments.current = [csvValues] 
            }
            else if(segments.current&&load>numberOfLoads){
                segments.current = [...segments.current, csvValues]
            }
            else if(segments.current&&load<=numberOfLoads){
                segments.current = [...segments.current, csvValues.splice(0, amountPerView)]
            }
            
        }

    }, [csvMap])

    useEffect(()=>{
        initCsv()
    }, [initCsv])


    const opts = {
        root: null, 
        rootMargin: `2500px`, 
        threshold: 0, 
    }

    const {setRef, stopObserve} = useObserver(action, opts)

    function action(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]){
        entries.forEach(entry=>{
            if(!segments.current){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    action(entries)
                }, 2000)
            }
            else if(segments.current&&entry.isIntersecting){
                if([...segments.current.entries()].length>chunk.current.load){
                    console.log(chunk.current.load)
                    const setSeg = segments.current[chunk.current.load]
                    pageSegments.current = !pageSegments.current?[setSeg]:[...pageSegments.current, setSeg]
                    chunk.current = {amountPerView: chunk.current.amountPerView, load: chunk.current.load+1}
                    setPageSet(prev=>prev+1)
                }

            }
        })
    }

    const addSegment: React.JSX.Element = useMemo(() => {
        if(!pageSegments.current){
            return (
                <div>Loading....</div>
            )
        }
        return (
            <CsvContainer chunk={chunk.current} pageSegments={pageSegments.current}  rowHeight={rowHeight.current}/>
            )
    }, [pagesSet])

    return (
        <div style={{height: '100vh', width: '100vw', overflow: 'hidden'}}>

                {
                !csv?<h1>Upload Csv</h1>:null
                }
                <div ref={spreadsheetRef} id="sheetContainer" key='1' style={{perspective: '1px', height: '100vh', width: '100vw', overflowY: 'scroll', overflowX: 'scroll', flexDirection: 'column'}}>               
                {
                    !pageSegments
                    ?
                    <h1>Loading</h1>
                    :
                    addSegment
                }
                    <div style={{height:'3px', width: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'none'}} ref={setRef} id="endCsv"></div>

                </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

CsvContainer.tsx

```js
"use client"

import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import styles from '../styles/csvView.module.css';
import CsvSegment from "./CsvSegment";


type Props = {
    pageSegments: Map<string, string>[][],
    chunk: { 
        load: number, 
        amountPerView: number
    },
    rowHeight: number,
}

export default function CsvContainer(props: Props) {
    const {pageSegments, chunk, rowHeight} = props;

  return (
    <>
        {
            pageSegments.map((seg, index)=>{
                return (
                    <CsvSegment key={`${index}`} length={chunk.amountPerView} rowHeight={rowHeight} index={index} segment={seg}/>
                )})
        }
    </>
  )
}
```

CsvSegment.tsx

```js
"use client"

import { useState } from "react";
import styles from '../styles/csvView.module.css';
import CsvRow from './CsvRow'


type Props = {
    index: number,
    segment: Map<string, string>[],
    length: number, 
    rowHeight: number
}

export default function CsvSegment(props: Props) {
    const {index, segment, length, rowHeight} = props;
  return (
    
    <div key={index} id={`csv-segment-${index}`} style={{ width: 'fit-content', height: 'fit-content', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        {
            segment.map((row, inx)=>{
                const rowIndex = inx+(index*length)
                return (
                    <CsvRow key={rowIndex} row={row} rowHeight={rowHeight} index={rowIndex}/>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
         
  )
}
```

CsvRow.tsx

```js
"use client"

import { useState } from "react";
import styles from '../styles/csvView.module.css';
import CsvCell from "./CsvCell";


type Props = {
    index: number,
    row: Map<string, string>,
    rowHeight: number,
    selected?: boolean
}

export default function CsvRow(props: Props) {
    const {index, row, rowHeight} = props;
    const selected = props.selected??false;
  return (
    
        <div id={`csv-row-${index}`} className={styles.segment} key={index} style={{height: rowHeight, minWidth: '100vw', width: 'fit-content', flexDirection: 'row', border: '1px solid black'}} >
            {
                [...row.entries()].map((c)=>{
                    return (
                        // <div key={`${index}-${c[0]}`} style={{overflow: "hidden"}}>
                            <CsvCell key={`${index}-${c[0]}`} row={`${index}`} column={c[0]} value={c[1]} selected={selected}/>
                        // </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
         
  )
}
```

CsvCell.tsx

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'


type Props = {
    row: string,
    column: string,
    value: string,
    selected?: boolean,
    isHeader?: boolean
}

function CsvCell(props: Props) {
    const {row, column, value} = props;
    const isSelected = props.selected??false;
    const isHeader = props.isHeader??false;
    const dblClickEvent = useRef<true|null>(null)
    const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState<string|null>(null);
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const setValue = async(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setNewValue(e.target.value);
    }

    const setDblClick = () => {
        dblClickEvent.current = true
        setTimeout(()=>{
            dblClickEvent.current = null
        }, 1200)
    }

    const onDblClick = () => {
        setSelected(false);
        setEditing(true);
    }
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log(row, column)
        if(column==='0'){
            console.log('Row ID')
            return;
        }
        if(dblClickEvent.current){
            return onDblClick()
        }
        setDblClick()
        setSelected(true)

    }

    return (
        <div onClick={()=>handleClick()} key={`${row}-${column}`} id={`csv-cell-${row}-${column}`} style={{minWidth: '50px', width: `60px`, borderLeft: `1px solid ${selected?'blue':'black'}`, borderRight: '1px solid black', overflow: 'hidden', backgroundColor: `${selected?'rgba(45,231,238, .07)':'none'}`}}>
        {
            !editing
            ?
            <>{newValue??value}</>
            :
            <input type="text" value={newValue??value} onChange={async (e)=>{return await setValue(e)}}/>
        }
        </div>

    )
}

export default CsvCell
```